# code doesn't insert the data into the database

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am trying a servlet that puts the data into the database:derbi *(that comes packed with netbeans)*. When a user clicks to submit data,the request follows to the `FormHandler servlet` *(given below)*  If any of the text-field was empty the request follows to another servlet `ErrorServlet` and if every thing was fine the request follows to the `Registered servlet`. But before the request follows to the `Registered Servlet` there is a small code that is written to insert the data into the database *(After this code the the user views the success page,that he has been registered)*.

Now the problem : The user fills all the text fields in the form and clicks submit. When he clicks submit,he sees the success page displaying *Registered Successfully* . But when i query the databse, i see that the data wasn't submitted to the databse. The rows and columns are empty ! I don't understand the reason for this .

Code for *FormHandler.java* :

```
package FormHandler;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class FormHandler extends HttpServlet {
  @Override
         public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {
    
}

@Override
        public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,IOException {
    
    String name = request.getParameter("Name");
    String email = request.getParameter("Email");
    String password = request.getParameter("Password");
    
    LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
    
    if(name.compareTo("") == 0 || email.compareTo("") == 0 || email.compareTo("") == 0) {
        list.add("One or more field's' left blank");
        request.setAttribute("ErrorList", list);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("ErrorServlet.view");
        rd.forward(request, response);
    } else {
        try {
            Context context = new InitialContext();
            DataSource ds = (DataSource)context.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDatasource");
            Connection connection = ds.getConnection();
           String sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO INFORMATION VALUES('" + name + "'," + "'" + email + "'," + "'" + password + "')";  
               PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
               ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();     
        }catch(Exception exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
        request.setAttribute("Data", list);
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Registered.view");
        rd.forward(request, response);
      }
    
    
}
```

}

*XML file*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>FormHandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>FormHandler.FormHandler</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Registered</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>FormHandler.Registered</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ErrorServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>FormHandler.ErrorServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>FormHandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/FormHandler.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<resource-ref>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyDatasource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Registered</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Registered.view</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ErrorServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/ErrorServlet.view</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

*Html* File :**[Code for html file](http://programworks.co.cc/htmlfile)**

*Note : I have already made a connection to database*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting somewhere a :

```
 java.sql.SQLException: No ResultSet was produced
```

because executing your UPDATE query with `executeQuery()` actually returns no resultset

Use:

```
 statement.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: yes ! I can see the data in the table now. But i get an exception when i click the submit button. Exception thrown by the server :`HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

descriptionThe server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

java.util.NoSuchElementException

note The full stack traces of the exception and its root causes are available in the GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.1 logs.` **What could be the reason for this ?**

Comment: It's another problem unrelated to database connection; i see you are putting an empty list in "*Data*" request attribute. What do you intend to do with that? My guess is another servlet or jsp is trying to access it, without checking bounds. If not, post your stacktrace in your question.

Comment: Another thing: you should definitely use setString() methods for your prepared statement, as suggested by harry above. It manages to escape strings for you (your current query will probably give an exception if some of the input parameters contain a single quote character).

Comment: though it doesn't give the exception,it doesn't store the data if the name has a single quote. Can you tell the reason ?

Comment: because you already use single quotes in the sql statement, if one of the paramenters includes a single quote, the sql becomes an invalid statement (ie *insert into information values ('su'hail','..','..')* ); you should definitely check your logs for exceptions (as glassfish itself suggests): in your *catch* expression add a *exc.printStackTrace()* because your swallowing it

Comment: @SuhailGupta you are using servlet and have written :  System.out.println(exc);? change it to out.println(exc); to trace exception. it will be better if you will write your entire code with in a try block and check where exactly you are getting exception.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
 PreparedStatement ps2=null;
 ps2 = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO INFORMATION( colname1, colname2,colname3) VALUES(? ,? ,?)");

          ps2.setString(1, name);
          ps2.setString(2, email);
          ps2.setString(3, password);

      try {
      rs=ps2.executeUpdate();  
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
            // catch if any exception 
        }
```